# Focus() on TextBox does not work

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, axacropdf

I have a Form with a `TextBox` in it. Every time the text changes i use the `TextChanged` Event to create a PDF-file and load it to an `AxAcroPDF`-Object in the same Form. This works fine, but then the `TextBox` loses focus and for some reason the `textBox.Focus()` after loading the file doesn't work.

Has anyone ideas how I can arrange that you can go on typing while refreshing the PDF?

**EDIT:**

i had another idea, i made a separate thread where i update the PDF and in the `TextChanged`-event i only set a flag. But now im getting a strange error

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'AcroPDFLib.IAcroAXDocShim'.
```

Comment: I think you should set .SelectedControl in the form to the TextBox instance at design time. You cannot set the focussed control in the form loader (if I remember correctly). Sorry I am not sure about the property name, could be .FocusedControl or something.

Comment: Is textbox control hosted inside groupbox, panel or any other container ?

Comment: How you load the file? Look for some kind of event triggered when the file finished loading and only then set the focus. Otherwise, try use timer for this.

Comment: @TheBlastOne: couldnt find the property you meant, theres no focus in form.controls or sth. like that

Comment: @Danilo Vulović : No, simple testform, only a button, a textbox and the pdf-viewer

Comment: @ShadowWizard : the com-object has a method named LoadFile(), i already looked for a suitable event but i couldnt find one, and a timer isnt the best solution when you want to typa and you have to wait until the textbox has focus again

Comment: In the form´s Shown event, call the control´s Focus method. Report back what happens. (Don´t do it in the FormLoad oder FormLoaded or what have you event)

Comment: Is the PDF com component the culprit? Does it work if you remove it temporarily?

Comment: @TheBlastOne The result is that after the startup the textbox has focus, but after typing the first letter it still loses focus and doesnt get it back

Comment: @TheBlastOne i tried Controls.Remove(axAcroPDF1); axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(filename); Controls.Add(axAcroPDF1); but same result

Comment: No, remove the PDF component at design time, comment all references, and report what happens.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17441/discussion-between-theblastone-and-saschaw)

Comment: ehm, that wont make any sense because i want to show a preview of the generated pdf. i think you are right, its the com-object and when i tried it with another thread the textbox kept focus so it definitely has to be the pdf-component. but without it the application is useless ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im so ashamed of myself, i found a really, really dirty hack, but it works...
I did the following:

When i write a text in the MessageBox i rewrite my PDF in the TextChange-Event. In the same method i store the Control that has focus (when calling the LoadFile on the PDF-Object this Control still loses focus). And now the dirty work comes: I implemented a Thread that constantly sets focus to the Control stored in the variable. In the Leave-Event of the TextBox i reset the variable so other controls wont be blocked.

Its a really dirty hack i know, but now i can instantly "edit" a pdf with my own form, which is a nice eyecandy ;)

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
textBox.Select();
textBox.Focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get .Focus() and .Select() to work so I used Jquery and it works perfectly.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".contentWrapper input")[0].focus();
    }, 100);
});
```